# Why the refresh on the model does not work?

Tags: sapui5

Maybe I don't really understand the `this.getView().getModel().refresh(true)` or `updateBindings`.. Somehow it doesn't refresh the model, or my main idea is wrong. I mean; I can do a workaround to call a function that reads the odata service again, but this is not really beautiful. So, I read the Model in the `onInit`

```js
onInit: function () {
  var that = this;
  var oViewModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({});
  this.getView().setModel(oViewModel, "detailView");
  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oViewModel,"detailView");
  var oFilter = [];
  var zAppFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("XXX", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "XXXX");
  oFilter.push(zAppFilter);
  var oModel = that.getView().getModel();
  oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("TwoWay");
  oModel.read("/XXXXSet", {
    filters: oFilter,
    success: function (oData) {
      that.getView().getModel("detailView").setData(oData.results);
    },
    // ...
  });
},
```

I use this `"detailView"`-JSONModel model in my view for bindings. This works.. Now, the *add* or *delete* function for example:

```js
onDelete: function (oEvent) {
  var that = this;
  var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
  var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getParent();
  var oSourceID = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext("detailView").getObject().Zid;
  oModel.remove("/XXX(XXX='XXX',XXXX='" + XXXX+ "')", {
    method: "DELETE",
    success: function(data) {
      that.getView().getModel("detailView").refresh(true);
      sap.ui.getCore().getModel("detailView").refresh(true);
    },
    // ...
  });
},
```

**That does not work..** but why? I mean also when I do `updateBindings` or something else. Am I understanding or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSONModel is not connected to anything. It's just a bunch of JSON data. So if you tell it to refresh, how should it know where to get the new data?

What `refresh` **does not do** is getting new data.

What `refresh` actually does (in a JSONModel) is telling the bindings that it has new data. One of these bindings can be the items of a `sap.m.List` for example. The list then knows that it needs to rerender to show the new data.

If you don't fetch new data and call refresh nothing will happen. The actual data is still the same.

> i can do a workaround to call a function that reads agean the odata service but this is not really beautyfull

Well using an additional JSONModel when you already have a perfectly fine ODataModel isn't beautiful in the first place. If you just dropped your JSONModel and bound your view to your ODataModel then the view would automatically update after calling `remove`.

---

To bind the view to your ODataModel you can start with

```
<Table id="table0" items="{/XXXXSet}">
```

Don't forget to remove `detailView` from your cells.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing a client-side model (`JSONModel`) with a server-side model (`ODataModel`), expecting them to synchronize.

Client-side models and server-side models are two separate models serving two different purposes.

### Client-side models

The main purpose of the client-side models is to provide and to sync data that are only available during the runtime of the application. If the app is gone, the data are gone. Some of the prominent use cases of client side models are:

- Device model via `JSONModel` which provides information about user's device and its states.
- `ResourceModel` which provides client side translatable UI texts for i18n purposes.
- Synchronizing states from UI or application

The models here are **not** aware of any server-side data, and they shouldn't since it's not their purpose.

When dealing with a remote data provider that complies with a certain specification (e.g. *OData* or *[FHIR](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-fhir)*), the appropriate server-side model should be used **instead**.

### Server-side models

Server-side models, such as `ODataModel`, have the advantage that they're server aware.
They know how to fetch, delete, update, create data, and even call functions from the backend system. They can be used to share states between the client and the server efficiently.

How? Simply use the server-side model in the binding definition directly. With OData as the default model for example:

```xml
<List items="{
  path: '/MyEntitySet',
  filters: [
    {
      path: 'ThatProperty',
      operator: 'EQ',
      value1: 'something'
    }
  ]
}"> <!-- given "MyEntitySet", "ThatProperty", "EntityTitle", and "EntityDesc" are defined in $metadata -->
  <StandardListItem title="{EntityTitle}" description="{EntityDesc}" />
</List>
```

This creates an [`ODataListBinding`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding) instance which will send a request to the service with the following URL:

`https://....svc/MyEntitySet?$filter=ThatProperty eq 'something'`

When the request succeeds, the list will show the entities accordingly. Afterwards, when calling `myODataModel.remove(...);`, the corresponding list will be refreshed automatically.

---

## TL;DR

> Am I understanding or doing something wrong?

Yes. Having an intermediate `JSONModel` in such cases is a common anti-pattern creating high maintenance costs. Try using the `ODataModel` only. The framework will do the work for you.